# How to read sms and delete without save in inbox

Tags: android, sms

I want to read a sms from specific number then delete without saving it in inbox. Below is my code which read sms but this code saves the SMS in the inbox.
How can I do delete a sms from specific number after read it?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
public static  String SMSstr;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";  

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                

            String phNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  

            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            if ("15555215556".equals(phNum))
            {
                // delete code goes here

                Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                l.putExtra("msg",str);
                l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(context, "SucessFull Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


         <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
     <!--       <intent-filter >-->
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
       </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the message simply call the `abortBroadcast()` after you check for the desired source!

Answer (score 1):

Try following code,

```
String specificPhoneNumber = "9898989898";

String addr = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress().trim();  // to get the SMS Number

if ( addr.trim().equals ( specificPhoneNumber.trim() )
{
      // delete SMS
      Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);
      String pid = c.getString(1);
      String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + pid; 
      getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
}
```

Comment: insert my code of if block after your this statement `if ("15555215556".equals(phNum))`

Comment: The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type SmsReceiver

Comment: press Ctrl+Space Key and it will import its necessary library :)

Comment: Nopes, I dont want to do spoon feeding, try it that small part your self now. you can also search on SO's other post.

Comment: @Lucifer 'c.getString(1);' gets the pid of first message from the inbox?